# Understanding the faster approach to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

The problem statement is given at [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/YOUTUBE/)  and is a s follows:-

> N students are bored in computer class so they watch funny video clips
>   on YouTube.
>
> The site contains K popular clips, numbered 1 through N. When a video
>   clip is watched, a list of similar video clips is displayed on the
>   side.
>
> Every student picks a video clip from the main page and starts
>   watching it. After exactly one minute every student gets bored of his
>   or her video clip, so he opens the first video clip from the list of
>   similar clips on the side (even if he already watched that clip).
>
> Write a program that determines for each student which video clip he
>   will be watching during the M-th minute of the class.

Now i know how to solve this we find the path and if it contains a cycle. We get the answer using its period.

But I have found a faster approach on the internet to do this,as it being an undocumented code, and me being a novice, I am not able to figure out whats happening in the below code.

```
    int N = in.nextInt (), K = in.nextInt (), M = in.nextInt () - 1;//Reading input

    int log = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros (Integer.highestOneBit (M)) + 1;

    int [][] next = new int [K][log + 1];

    int [] start = new int [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        start [i] = in.nextInt () - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        next [i][0] = in.nextInt () - 1;

    for (int i = 1; 1 << i <= M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < K; j++)
            next [j][i] = next [next [j][i - 1]][i - 1];

    for (int i = 0; 1 << i <= M; i++)
        if (((1 << i) & M) > 0)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                start [j] = next [start [j]][i];

    out.print (start [0] + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        out.print (" " + (start [i] + 1)); //writing output
```

How can we solve the problem efficiently/without getting in fuss of finding cycles?
Or How is the above code solving the problem?

Comment: you should add a language tag or the language agnostic tag

Comment: why are cycles relevant here? It doesn't matter, if a student already watched a video, so you can ignore cycles.

Comment: @Paul  " he opens the first video clip from the list of similar clips on the side (**even if he already watched that clip**)."

Comment: @Sam I can read quite well and my english isn't **that** bad (atleast I hope). So why does the fact that the videos don't need a visited-state imply that you need to detect cycles?

Comment: @Sam: Yes. That means that the clip sequence is constant. It doesn't depend on a state. Therefore, the n-th clip after each clip can be precalculated. The posted solution does just that, but in a clever way:

Comment: @Paul sorry ,It might be just that i am thinking of this in a wrong way.

Comment: @MOehm Can you elaborate how can we pre calculate the nth clip after each clip?

Comment: You have said that you are a novice, so let me ask you something first: Are you familiar with bitwise operations? Or, in the present example, do you understand what the `<<` and `&` operators mean? Unserstanding these is the key to understanding how the algorithm calculates the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th, 16th and so on clip.

Comment: @MOehm Yes,I do understand the bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses exponentiation by squaring for a matrix. For each video, the list of related videos is predetermined and thus you know which video is first in this list. So for each video you know which video you will watch next.

You have a simple transformation matrix. At row `i` you will have a single `1` - at the index of the video that is next after video number `i` and all remaining elements will be 0. Take this matrix and raise it to `m-1` - th degree and you will get a transformation matrix that shows which video you will be watching in the m-th minute if you started with video `i`. This also explains why the author of the solution subtracts 1 from the input for `M` after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is ignoring cicles. He uses a bottom up dynamic programming method similar to that of the fast exponentiation. He uses the next matrix to store the next position of each student after 1, 2, 2^2, etc. steps. That's the work of the 3rd for. Then, in the 4th for, he constructs M in binary. This way, if M = 2^3 + 2^0, the place of each student can be computed calculating first the position after 2^0 minutes assigning this as the base position and then calculating the position after 2^3 minutes from this new position.

If you look at info about fast exponentiation, you'll see that this O(N log(M)) memoization space used is not necessary, as there's only one request you can calculate the final position while doing the "fast exponentiation" step.